# Swap css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, html

I would like to swap classes in two links using jQuery. I got a HTML code like:

```
<div class="showHide1">
   <a id="aaa" class="show">AAA</a>
   <a id="bbb" class="hide">BBB</a>
</div>

<div class="showHide2">
   <a id="aaa" class="show">AAA</a>
   <a id="bbb" class="hide">BBB</a>
</div>
```

and a simple .css file :

```
.show {
    display: block;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Now I want to swap classes in both links after clicking somewhere on the "showHide" div.

```
$('#showHide1').click(function() {
    if ($("#aaa").hasClass('show')) {
        $("#aaa").attr("class","hide");
    }
    else {
        $("#aaa").attr("class","show");
    }

    if ($("#bbb").hasClass('hide')) {
        $("#bbb").attr("class","show");
    }
    else {
        $("#bbb").attr("class","hide");
    } `
```

I'm sure there is a better way to solve this problem, because this only works for "showHide1" div, and I have to copy almost the same code to get it working for a "showHide2" div. Could anyone show me a better solution?

Thanks

Dawid

Comment: Side note: ids on a page should be unique.

Comment: I see the only difference between your classes is the `display`. If this is all your trying to do, you could use jQuery's .show() and .hide() methods (or fadeIn, fadeOut, etc.) if not, the above two answers have got it nailed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand of cdeszaq's answer, instead of having `.show` and `.hide` only use `.hide` then you can use the following:

HTML:

```
<div id="showHide1" class="showHide">
   <a id="aaa">AAA</a>
   <a id="bbb" class="hide">BBB</a>
</div>

<div id="showHide2" class="showHide">
   <a id="aaa">AAA</a>
   <a id="bbb" class="hide">BBB</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.showHide').click(function() {
   $('a', this).toggleClass('hide'); //I had inverted my selector and context earlier, this is correct
});
```

Comment: @cdeszaq thanks, it was your idea but when I wrote this all you had was a link to toggleClass so I just wanted to give a code example. I see you edited though, sorry :P

Comment: @Chad - Yeah, I tend to throw down a quick, fast answer and then usually go back and expand the context and more info.

Comment: @Drackir - Why? My initial answer always answers the question asked and isn't just a 1/2-assed attempt at an answer. For many questions, the not much is needed to fully answer the question. However, I prefer When I go back in, it is more to educate and provide the reasoning behind my answer. Isn't that what the ability to edit one's posts is for?

Comment: @cdeszaq - Because so many times have I worked on writing a good answer with an example and links, only to be "beat out" by someone who wrote "Yes you can" and then edited their answer within the 5 minute window.

Comment: @Drackir - I very, VERY rarely put my "1st draft" as something simple like a yes or no answer, and I also often have a link in there to my source, but I know what you mean. I too have felt that pain, but in the end, the best answer is what will "win", where "best" is what meets the OP's needs the best.

Comment: @cdeszaq - Yeah, but if I put my full answer and then the person who posted "Yes it is" edits theirs to put basically the same thing as mine, how is the OP supposed to know that I posted the full answer first? But regardless, that's just how it goes sometimes, which is why your comment made me sadface. :P @Chad: Sorry for the comment hijacking. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) instead of checking if the class is there, and then either adding or removing it. `.toggleClass()` already takes care of that logic for you.

Your code would be:

```
$('#showHide1').click(function() {
    $("#aaa")
        .toggleClass("hide")
        .toggleClass("hide");
    $("#bbb")
        .toggleClass("hide")
        .toggleClass("hide");
});
```

Note: This assumes that the `show` and `hide` classes start off in the correct state.

Answer (score 0):

I think youve got you id's and classes mixed up try this html:

```
<div id="showHide1">
   <a class="show aaa">AAA</a>
   <a class="hide bbb">BBB</a>
</div>

<div id="showHide2">
   <a class="show aaa">AAA</a>
   <a class="hide bbb">BBB</a>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('#showHide1, #showHide2').click(function() {
    var a_showing = $('.aaa.show', this);
    var a_hiding  = $('.aaa.hide', this);
    var b_showing = $('.bbb.show', this);
    var b_hiding  = $('.bbb.hide', this);
    a_showing.addClass('hide').removeClass('show')
    a_hiding.addClass('show').removeClass('hide')
    b_showing.addClass('hide').removeClass('show')
    b_hiding.addClass('show').removeClass('hide')
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/qMBRq/

Comment: You have so much code to do something so small. Yes, the IDs are wonky, but having 4 variables, and the 4 more lines...Occam would be rolling over in his grave if he actually existed.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/T8Vta/) is how I would do it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="showhide">
   <a id="aaa1" class="show">AAA</a>
   <a id="bbb1" class="hide">BBB</a>
</div>

<div class="showhide">
   <a id="aaa2" class="show">AAA</a>
   <a id="bbb2" class="hide">BBB</a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() { 
    $('a.hide').hide();
    $('div.showhide').click(function() {
        $(this).children('a').toggle();
    });
});
```

This way, if the user doesn't have JavaScript enabled, they'll still be able to see everything. It may cause a *flash of unstyled content* (not exactly, but basically) since you're adding the hide after the DOM is ready via JavaScript. Now, that may or may not be important for you so you'll have to decide.