# Change width of floated item when pushed down

Tags: html, css-float

I have 2 divs next to each other. The left hand one is 600px wide and the right hand is 200px wide, plus a little spacing etc. Both div's are floated left so that if the page is displayed in a smaller window the right hand div drops down below.

What is want is for that right hand div to expand and become 600px wide if it is pushed onto the second row. But if there is 200px of space on the top row then I want it to display there at 200px.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really look into [**media queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries) if you're trying to adapt your page for mobile devices.

```css
#yourSecondDiv {
    width: 200px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 799px) {
    #yourSecondDiv {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Might be helpful also - [**media queries for standard devices**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: This is the first time i have heard of this feature, and i would like to know if it is supported by different desktop browsers ? and is it part of the CSS3 Specification ?

Comment: @Sniffer It is part of [***CSS3 specs***](http://caniuse.com/#search=media%20queries) and you can use it in most desktop browsers as well (older IE-s have no support, as usual)

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if this is possible in HTML or CSS, i think you need a little JavaScript, and i would go into [JQuery](http://jquery.com) if this is the case

Answer (score 0):

That seems like something that you could do with javascript. I'm guessing you can check to see if the div has been pushed down when the page width is smaller. Then you just swap out the CSS and put in the width to be 600px. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902698/swap-css-class). As kindly explained in another posting. This may or may not work. If it does that's awesome if not then oh well. Let me know what you come up with for a solution.